Divisibility of discriminants in field towers
I'm studying Marcus's Number Fields, and am stuck in Exercise 8 of Chapter 2, which asks to prove that the $p$-th cyclotomic field contains either $\sqrt{p}$ or $\sqrt{-p}$ depending on whether $p$ is $1$ or $-1\pmod 4$. The exercise hints that I should use the discriminant of the cyclotomic field, which has been calculated in Chapter 2 to be $\pm p^{p-2}$.
Now I understand why a unique quadratic subfield exists (by the structure of the Galois group), and I understand why the discriminant of $Q[\sqrt{d}]$ is either $d$ when $d\equiv 1\pmod 4$ or else $4d$. It seems that I'm meant to use the fact that the discriminant of the subfield must divide the discriminant of the field to conclude the proof. But that fact is not stated or used in Chapter 2. When I look up its proof in other textbooks, it seems to go through the notion of a relative discriminant (an ideal rather than a number), which coincides with the numeric discriminant when the base ring is $Z$ (or any PID), with other concepts like the different playing roles in the proof.
That's a lot of machinery Marcus does not develop (at least this early in the book), which makes me suspect there's perhaps an easier way to get to the fact that the quadratic subfield must be $Q[\sqrt{p}]$ or $Q[\sqrt{-p}]$, while still using the discriminant. Is there?

taking $\omega$  as a primitive $p$-th root of unity. Let $x$  be the sum $ x = \sum_{k=1}^{(p-1/2)}  \omega^{(k^2)}.$   If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$  then $x^2 + x - \frac{p-1}{4} = 0.$  If $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$  then $x^2 + x + \frac{p+1}{4} = 0.$  Just one of those things.

You wrote

It seems that I'm meant to use the fact that the discriminant of the subfield must divide the discriminant of the field to conclude the proof.

Exercise 8 never brings this up.  You are not meant to use that fact since, as you already pointed out, such a divisibility is not yet mentioned at that point in the book.
Think instead about two ways to calculate the discriminant $D$ of $\{1,\omega, \ldots, \omega^{p-2}\}$. One way, which you mention, is $D = \pm p^{p-2}$ where, by Theorem 8 in Chapter 2, the $+$ sign holds when $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and not otherwise.  Thus when $p$ is an odd prime, $D = p^{p-2}$ when $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and $D = -p^{p-2}$ when $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$. A second way is by the definition of $D$, which says
$$
D = \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq p-2} (\omega^j - \omega^i)^2,
$$
so $D$ is a square in $\mathbf Q(\omega)$. Thus $\sqrt{D} \in \mathbf Q(\omega)$. Now take cases when $p$ is $1$ or $-1 \bmod 4$.

First, your proposed approach wouldn't work because “the discriminant of the subfield” assumes that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt d)$ is a subfield to begin with, which is what you're trying to prove.
Second, I think you should have the fact available that the discriminant of a field extension is an element of that field; try using that.

To expand, I meant this argument: we know that the Galois group of $Q[w]/Q$ is isomorphic to $Z_p^*$, the multiplicative group of integers between $1$ and $p$ relatively prime to $p$, which, because $p$ is an odd prime, is a cyclic group of order $p-1$ that has a unique subgroup of order $2$, therefore $Q[w]$ has a unique subfield of degree $2$ over $Q$. That subfield must be some $Q[\sqrt{d}]$, it'll have a discriminant $4d$ or $d$, but since it must divide $p^{p-2}$, it must be $d$ with $d=\pm p$, depending on which of them is $1 \pmod 4$. I don't think this argument is circular - is it?

I'll answer my own question. Yes, there's a way to directly prove the presence of $\sqrt{\pm p}$ in $p$-th cyclotimic group, without using the full generality of "the discrimimant of a subfield divides the discriminant of the field".
We know that the discriminant of $Q[\omega]$ is $\pm p^{p-2}$, the sign depending on whether $p$ is $1 \pmod 4$. This discriminant is the square of a determinant of a matrix with entries of the form $\sigma_i(a_j)$, where $\sigma_i$ goes through embeddings of $Q[\omega]$ in $\mathbb C$, and $a_j$ goes through some integral basis. Now specifically for cyclotomic fields, we know that all embeddings send $\omega$ to some $\omega^k$. Thus embeddings of cyclotomic fields are automorphisms; and all the $\sigma_i(a_j)$ remain in $Q[\omega]$; and so does the determinant of the matrix, which is a square root of the discriminant.
It follows that $\sqrt{\pm p^{p-2}}$ is in $Q[\omega]$. As $p$ is odd, $\sqrt{p^{p-1}}$ is an integer and is also in $Q[\omega]$. Dividing the latter by the former, we see that $\sqrt{\pm p}$ is in $Q[\omega]$, as required.
